# Why is the wifi network visible to everybody but me?

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

Recently my flatmate changed the maximum number of devices that can connect to our Wifi and since then **I cannot see our Wifi network**.

I am the only one in my household using Ubuntu. I logged into our rooter using a webbrowser and I can see other people's **non-Ubuntu devices** connected and working flawlessly. Their owners can see the wifi and can connect anytime. When I connect by cable, I can see my computer too, but it is not possible to connect wirelessly.

Here are the things I tried:

1. I checked that I am not **blacklisted** - I am not
2. I tried to **"Connect to hidden Wifi network"**, entered SSID and password - no effect
3. I **restarted** the router multiple times - no effect

Please, what can be causing this and what can I do next?

**EDIT:**

I am using an **Orange Livebox** and here is a screenshot of the devices connected:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't have too many devices connected? What router do you guys use?

Comment: @Seth Yes, the maximum number is 12 and there are only 7 devices connected. I tried it also when there were only 2 devices.

Comment: I haven't used this particular router, but one I used had a limit on the number of MAC addresses you could put into the access list, with the older ones falling off the list as new ones were added. Actually, it was worse than that; the old ones were still in the list, but only the most recently-entered 4 would be allowed access. I had to remove the whole access list and re-enter all of them to fix things.